# HTML Form With Input And Text Area, Processed With PHP Then Redirect Back With Values Typed

Tags: php, html

I have a simple HTML Form as follow (form.html) :

```
<form id="tips-message-notes" action="notessaved.php" method="post" class="general-form">
<div class="input-wrap">
<input type="text" name="title" value="'.$Title.'"/>
</div><!-- .input-wrap -->
<div class="input-wrap">
<textarea cols="" rows="" name="article" class="myTextEditor">'.$Article.'</textarea>
</div><!-- .input-wrap -->
<div class="button-wrap">
<input type="submit" name="publish" value="Publish" class="submit-btn" />
<input type="submit" name="draft" value="Save Draft" class="draft-btn" />
</div><!-- .button-wrap -->
</form>
```

when user click submit button, this PHP will process database insertion (database.php) :

```
<?php
$Title = $_POST['title'];
$Article = $_POST['article'];

$con = mysql_connect("server","username","password");
if (!$con)
{
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("my_db", $con);

mysql_query("INSERT INTO Table (Title, Article)
VALUES ('$Title', '$Article')");

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

the problem is.. how to redirect back to form.html after user hit submit button with values on those input and text area submitted before?

please note that text area might have more than 1024 characters. so I don't think by putting $article on URL and using GET method on form.html is good idea. I hope I can see other technique from you... thanks!

Comment: http://us2.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php

Comment: header( 'Location: http://www.yoursite.com/form.html' ) ;

Comment: if you want to redirect back to the form.html I would suggest to insert data using ajax and on successful insertion of data just reload the page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.session.php

You need to use the PHP session.

As a very, very basic tutorial:

1. Put `session_start()` at the start of every page *before* emitting any output.
2. write the `_POST` values to `_SESSION`
3. In your form display page, have: `$Articles = htmlspecialchars($_SESSION['Articles']);`, etc.

This is the only reliable way to carry the data between multiple pages.

---

Sanitize your inputs to queries.  Either use prepared statements with `PDO` (or `mysqli`) or at a bare minimum, run `mysql_real_escape_string` on the `_POST` inputs to the query first.

Answer (score 1):

A common practice is to put the PHP on the same page as the form and enclose the PHP inside this:

```
<?php 

if($_POST)
{
// your processing code here
}

?>
```

Then, you can just submit your form to itself and the values will be processed on the same page.  You can then include this in your textbox which will fill it with the $_POST'd value:

```
<textarea><?php echo $_POST['textarea']; ?></textarea>
```

Notice:  This is not secure.  Please ask how you can secure it if you are not sure.

Notice:  While this is acceptable; a better design is to use MVC.

Answer (score 1):

Add `$_POST` to the `$_SESSION` on the database page:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['post'] = $_POST;
```

Use `header` function to redirect to the `form.html` page:

```
header('Location: http://mydomina/form.html');
```

Write back the data from `$_SESSION['post']` into the form fields:

```
<texarea><?php echo $_SESSION['post']['article']; ?></textarea>
```

Consider security issues when working on database also.

Answer (score 0):

You can use PHP SESSION for this.

http://php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php